# Problems With Interactive Viewers Running R in VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am getting started with running R scripts in VSCode.  Things are generally running fine, except for unexpected results with some of the viewers.  I'm running Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6.

First, any table / list  I try to view (using the View() command) generates this error:

```
Error in check_for_XQuartz(file.path(R.home("modules"), "R_de.so")) : 
  X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from www.xquartz.org
```

So I went ahead and installed XQuartz.  Viewing dataframes then worked, but it spawned a separate window, rather than a VSCode tab, that was very primitive: slow to render, without any interactivity (no sorting of columns or searching, etc. of the type shown at https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Interactive-viewers).

Second, I'm having similar problems with rendering plots.  Plotting works, but it spawns a separate window, titled "Quartz 2 (*)", rather rendering in VSCode.

I have installed httpgd, and enabled r.plot.useHttpgd in VSCode settings.

Any advice, anyone?  Big thanks in advance.

Comment: In the status bar do you see 'R: [a number]'? If not, you may need to activate the session watcher as described here: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Session-watcher

Comment: @andycraig: That did it!  Big thanks from a VSCode noob.